# A community of loners - what makes them still want to be considered a part of the "community"

Tags: humans, psychology, trans-humanism

Imagine a time where mankind is everywhere in the galaxy, in fact we gotten so far past post scarcity economy that the concept of money is only talked about in reference to far history, every man\woman\etc not only has a spaceship that is pretty much as arbitrarily large as he wants (some reaching the size of the sun) to himself but it also has a full manufacturing ability to create everything he wanted (it's as easy as saying "ship print me the the louvre" and you have a perfect louvre within seconds).

Everyone gains independence at a very early age (school isn't really needed and the ship teaches you everything you need to know by the time your six by broadcasting it into your brain during a one night of sleep) and have their spaceship made to go on and live their life very early on.

Now we're social animals but the thing is that even with all this super manufacturing abilities (which are handwaved to work with the ship always collecting enough mass from mining asteroids & having a bio-bay grow the raw materials needed non stop) the one limit we can't pass is the speed of light limit, this means that most go years between seeing another ship\human (which at this point are considered almost the same being as each single human travels on a single ship).

Most people only come across other human beings a handful of times in their lifetime with everything else needed supplied by the ship which can also simulate needed human contact & warmth, and yes this includes sex (which feels as real as one desires it to be, up to the point where it's impossible to tell apart from the real thing)

The end result of all this time alone & with everything needed, wanted & desired supplied without another human being around people are loners & don't really feel the need to socialize with "real" humans anymore.

**Now my question is why being loners who have all their needs supplied (and yes it's all their needs... even babies are created by the ship) why would this future people still feel the need to consider themselves part of the "human" community?**

Comment: It is only natural for them to continue thinking of themselves as humans. But you probably mean whether they want to participate in some kind of "community activities"?

Comment: I'd love to answer this, but it's been proposed that "[Why would someone X?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6130#6338)" questions are off-topic as either too broad or [primarily opinion-based](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6437/40609) These kinds of questions are difficult to answer because they're often a function of plot and not a rule of worldbuilding.  What rule or system of your world are you asking about?  What basis of judgement will you use to choose a best answer?  VTC:POB until clarified.

Comment: I mean them wanting to be considered to be part of the community rather then becoming a hermit that hates other people and just want to be left alone

Comment: @cypher if that's your goal, you should provide some activities that force people to be a part of community rather than be completely isolated. For example, in today's world some people may never go out and may have no real life friends - but their online activity can be thremendous.

Comment: Because we're biologically hardwired that way. It's of little use presenting logic to an innate psychological construct and expecting the construct to change. Though I suspect such an advanced civilization would a) have pills to combat this and b) wouldn't even have this setup in the first place. Insular communities, yes, but what would possess the human race to do *this*?

Answer (score 3):

Realistically nothing, some people may want companionship beyond their ship, others not.

Novelty value in interacting with other humans is a possibility.

But you have already gotten rid of the greatest social urges so I assume people have lost most of the little ones as well. You've broken the nuclear family bonds which is one of our defining traits, so I'm not sure these are actually humans anymore, but certainly their whole outlook would be very different and egocentric. We would classify them as insane.

Answer (score 3):

## For the Ultimate Challenge

> "I abhor the idea of a perfect world. It would bore me to tears."
>   - Shelby Foote
>
> "Man is sometimes extraordinarily, passionately, in love with suffering" - Fyodor Dostoevsky

Dostoevsky believed that if we ever achieved Utopia, the first thing we would do is destroy it just so something interesting would happen.

One of the principle driving psychological forces in humans is the desire to be better, to grow, to face challenges, to overcome opposition.  It's the heart of almost all mythological tales, hero stories, and children's novels.  Face the fears; conquer yourself and your desires; make the world a better place.  Without this driving force, when hedonism reigns king, are we really free, or have we simply become slaves to our own desires?

> "There is a tyranny in the womb of every Utopia."
>   - Bertrand De Jouvenel

Your spaceships make us, as modern mathematician Eric Weinstein said, "Gods but for the wisdom."  And no, knowledge is not wisdom.

More to the point: **when you can have whatever you want, you'll get bored.** It's like playing every video game with unlimited health and ammo.  There's no challenge, no stakes.  When cheating has no consequences, and whatever you want is immediately available, there's nothing to strive against.  Nothing to try for.

So, then, what would be the *ultimate challenge*? Pick a planet, abandon the spaceships, and force yourself to live without them.  The consequences are real: suffering and death.  The need for human community becomes apparent.  There is no cheating.  While some may prefer to waste away in their spaceships on the constant "high" of pleasures and desires, some would want the greatest challenge: to suffer other people *without* godlike power.

Other humans; other consciences who are relatively equal in capacity, yet unique in features, becomes a challenge no spaceship can offer.  Challenges - something to strive against - is a huge motivator.

## For Love

> "My sense of the holy is bound up with the hope that some day my remote descendants will live in a global civilization in which love is pretty much the only law." - Richard M. Rorty

For many people, simulating loving relationships isn't "true" love - even if the simulation can imitate emotions, feelings, and struggles of relationships.  There's always that nagging aspect in the back of your mind that *you have total complete power*.  With one word you can have the ship change them, destroy them, make them better.

Relationships - loving someone for who they are - requires accepting them *with flaws*.  If there are no flaws, then is it really love?  If there are flaws, but only the ones you allow, are you loving them or who you want them to be?  If the only compromises in your relationship come because *you* controlled the situation, is it really compromise?

The desire to be a part of a human "community" can mean the desire **for love** - to be one among equals.  To love others as they are.  Not as your god nor as your slave, nor you as their god nor as their slave.  Just people.  Equals.  This sense of "a part of" and not "in total control of" seems to be an innate longing - at least for some people.

Although not everyone would be interested, certainly some humans would see the benefit of interacting with others not created for them at their will in a spaceship, but other people *who chose them*.  And that's an important aspect of love - if there are infinite people you can create you just spawn out humans until someone chooses you.  But to find a human you chooses you not because you deemed so (by creating them via order to the spaceship) but by free will and choice, whom you neither created nor killed, and have no authority over, this is a type of love no spaceship in your universe can recreate.

## For Religion or Philosophy

I'll make this one short - it's not far-fetched that such a future world would have people who still believe in one or more deities.  They, albeit the most powerful creatures in the universe, are still subsets of (and therefore subservient to) the universe itself.  Therein a call to a higher power, to spread "the message" or "revelations" from the deity to other humans would demand participation in human community.

Similarly, philosophically the meta-values of having relationships and sharing genuine interactions in a way not controlled by the ship might spurn a desire for a different type of relationship than what the ship has to offer.